# How to include special characters into a XAML static multi langage resource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, staticresource

I want to insert special characters into a XAML `StaticResource` comming from a multi langage resource.

This is the XAML piece of code I use:

```
...
xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:MyProject.Properties"
...
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static resx:Resources.text_20}"/>
```

where

```
text_20 = "Inter Frame&#x0a;delay"
```

set in each Resources files

[image]

The text that should be displayed is:

```
Inter Frame
delay
```

But what is displayed is:

```
Inter Frame&#x0a;delay
```

It seems that special characters are not interpreted when it is set in a resource file.

Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure but try escape characters instead e.g. `\r\n` for new line.

Comment: @aepot, I tried escape charaters, but the result is the same, displaying Inter Frame\r\ndelay

Comment: _"I tried escape charaters, but the result is the same, displaying Inter Frame\r\ndelay"_ -- please improve the question. Were you assigning the value in C# code, then as long as you aren't using a verbatim string (prefixed with `@`), then including `\r\n` will work. So you're either initializing the string differently than your question implies, or you're incorrectly using the string. There's not enough context in your question to know what you're doing wrong, but surely it is something simple and tantamount to a typographical error, if not an actual typographical error.

Comment: @Peter Duniho, I added some precision in the question. The issue comes from XAML not in C#. The text come from a resource language file so using @ before the string isn't relevant.

Comment: @sodjsn26fr please add some part of your xaml localization file to the question.

Comment: @Peter Duniho, I added more precision. The text is set into a localization file. It seems that XAML parser don't evaluate the resource string before displaying it.

Comment: Just finished surfing for solution. Looks like .resx file doesn't support any special characters out-of-the-box when you setting up localisatios via Visual Studio resource editor. So, one thing you may use in this case - `IValueConverter` with your binding, then you'll decide what will be feeding your Converter: escape characters or xml entities.

Comment: @aepot, thank you, I'll try searching a solution with you suggestion. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try in app.xaml

```
   <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="ress" ObjectType="{x:Type local:type}" />
```

and in c#

```
            words = (type) (Application.Current.Resources["ress"] as ObjectDataProvider)?.Data;
```

in c# making the (Where type is your class type) string with \\

Answer (score 0):

It seems that XAML parser don't evaluate the resource string before displaying it.

Temporarily I used literally `<Shift + Enter>` in the .resx resource editor to insert a carriage return.